# How to verify whether a certain transaction is mined by the newest block programmatically?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, blocks, raw-transaction

#### What I thought I should do

I implemented this functionality with Bitcoin Core through zmq support.

1. Keep "my transactions" through `zmq`'s `rawtx` topic.
2. When received `zmq`'s `rawblock`, decode the raw block, get transaction ids from it, compare them with 1's transaction id, and confirm them if matched.

So I thought I should be doing

1. Find something like Bitcoin Core.
2. Find some TCP interface.
3. Do the above 1-2.

#### What I tried so far

So first of all I chose to use `geth`, which is one of the most popular Ethereum-implementing node, and looked for [RPC-PUB-SUB docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB). I found that its `newPendingTransactions` subscription corresponds to `zmq`'s `rawtx`. But I couldn't seem to find what corresponds to `zmq`'s `rawblock`. Of course there's a `newHeads` subscription, but for [what the API returns](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB#example-2), I don't see any hint to decode which transactions are mined by that block.

Some library like [ethereumjs-block](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-block) does seem to create a block from raw Buffer though.

#### What I'm trying to do

Be independent as much as possible from what `geth`'s wallet system offers. The best thing is to only use that PUB-SUB functionality. (Get a raw block, decode it, get transactions, and so on.)

If I go one step back, I may do polling via, like, `eth_blocknumber` and `eth_getBlockByNumber`, but that's not what I want for now.

If there's other way around for this, please give me some rough idea. I don't mind using other Ethereum client.